# What should the output of a decision tree for a new data that has never been seen by the training data

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

Suppose that I am training a  data set, where it only consists of only one training example: [feature: 1 output: 1]. The feature and the output are both binary. Now if I want to predict the output of the tree corresponding to the input 0. What should the output be? This is an overly simplified example only for illustration purpose.

Comment: I think you've simplified your question to the point we might not have enough information to help you. In general, if you only have 1 data point (for any classification algorithm, not just random forest) then your classifier does not have enough information to do anything. It will classify ALL data points as belonging to the class of that first example until new data is introduced.

Comment: My point is that with a decision tree, you can only deal with patterns that are present in the training example(Do correct me if I am wrong). Suppose you have never seen the input [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] before in your training examples, how can you make your prediction based on the tree?

Comment: I think I get your point. While a decision tree can only deal with patterns from the training data, it doesn't need to have seen an identical data point to know how to classify it. For example, if your tree has never seen [1,1,1,1,1,1,1] before, but it has seen [1,1,1,1,0,0,0] and [0,0,0,0,1,1,1] then it has seen at had the opportunity to create branches based on all seven of our hypothetical variables. I would suggest playing around with some code and I think you'll pick up the intuition.

Comment: This page has a good beginners guide with graphs that could help you begin to understand it: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/a-guide-to-machine-learning-in-r-for-beginners-decision-trees-c24dfd490abb

Comment: I guess I am not so sure what to do about the case when you stop at a leaf node but that leaf node has no training data associated with it. Do you just take the label of its parent node?

Comment: Okay, I think that makes more sense. Yes, if that case did exist, take the parent node. I would note that if this is happening, it probably means that you need to prune your tree, or that you don't have enough data, or both. In any of these cases Random Forest has been shown to have much better reliability than a pure decision tree, and performing Random Forest analysis would almost certainly solve this problem.